# quadtree wont insert a node or split

Tags: c++, collision-detection

My insert function for my quadtree seems to not split the tree, it works fine for the 1st node I try to insert but then doesn't for the 2nd. I really can't pin point where it is going wrong. If you guys could help me find out why it won't insert as well as how I can fix this I would appreciate it. At the bottom of the post is the output.

If you need more details ask, if the problem isn't specific enough  I'll try to be more specific in the comments.

The code is based off of https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quad-tree/

my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int _x, int _y){
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
    Point(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
};

struct Square{
    int x, y, w, h;

    Point center;

    Square(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h){
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        w = _w;
        h = _h;

        center = Point(x + _w/2, y + _h/2);
    }
    Square(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        w = 0;
        h = 0;

        center = Point(0, 0);
    }
};

struct Node{
    Point point;
    int data;

    Node(Point _p, int _d){
        point = _p;
        data = _d;
    }
    Node(){
        point = Point(0, 0);
        data = 0;
    }

};

class Quad{
    Square area;

    Quad *NE; // top right
    Quad *NW; // top left
    Quad *SE; // bottum right
    Quad *SW; // bottum left

    Node *child; // quad contains a pointer to a node
    bool split;

    public:
        Quad(Square _a){
            area = _a;

            NE = NULL;
            NW = NULL;
            SE = NULL;
            SW = NULL;

            child = NULL;
            split = false;
        }
        Quad(){
            area = Square(0, 0, 0, 0);

            NE = NULL;
            NW = NULL;
            SE = NULL;
            SW = NULL;

            child = NULL;
            split = false;
        }

        bool inRange(Point p){
            return p.x <= area.w + area.x && p.x >= area.x && p.y <= area.h + area.y && p.y > area.y;
        }

        bool insert(Node *c){

            if(area.w >= 1 && area.h >= 1){
                if(child == NULL){
                    child = c;
                    return false;
                } // cant collide if there is nothing to collide with
            }

            if(area.w >= 1 && area.h >= 1 || area.w <= 1 && area.h <= 1){
                if(child != NULL){
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if(child != NULL){
                if(split == false){

                    NW = new Quad( Square(area.x, area.y, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    NE = new Quad( Square(area.w/2, area.y, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    SW = new Quad( Square(area.x, area.h/2, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    SE = new Quad( Square(area.w/2, area.h/2, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    split = true;
                    child = NULL;
                }
            }

            if(NW->inRange(c->point)){
                NW->insert(c);
            }
            if(NE->inRange(c->point)){
                NE->insert(c);
            }
            if(SW->inRange(c->point)){
                SW->insert(c);
            }
            if(SE->inRange(c->point)){
                SE->insert(c);
            }


        }

        Node *test(){

            if(child != NULL){
                return child;
            }

            return NULL;
        }

};

int main() {

    Node node_1( Point(10, 10) , 3);
    Node node_2( Point(2, 2) , 2);
    Quad quad( Square(0, 0, 16, 16) );
    cout<<quad.insert(&node_1)<<"\n";
    cout<<quad.insert(&node_2)<<"\n";
    cout<<quad.test();

    return 0;
}
/*Output:
0           this is good
1           this should be a 0
0x23fe14    this should be 0 also
*/
```

Edit: I made some changes to the insert function as seen below but it's still going down a path I would prefer it didn't as I have no clue what that path means or how to fix it.

new insert:

```
bool insert(Node *c){
        if(area.w >= 1 && area.h >= 1){
            cout<<"1\n";
            if(child == NULL){
                cout<<"2\n";
                child = c;
                return 0;
            }
            if(child == c){
                cout<<"3\n";
                return 0;
            }
            if(child != NULL){
                cout<<"4\n";
                if(area.w <= 1 && area.h <= 1){
                    cout<<"5\n";
                    return 0;
                }
                if(split == false){
                    cout<<"6\n";
                    NW = new Quad( Square(area.x, area.y, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    NE = new Quad( Square(area.w/2, area.y, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    SW = new Quad( Square(area.x, area.h/2, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    SE = new Quad( Square(area.w/2, area.h/2, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    split = true;
                    child = NULL;
                }
            }
        }


        if(area.center.x < c->point.x){
            cout<<"7\n";

            if(area.center.y < c->point.y){
                cout<<"8\n";
                NE->insert(c);
            }
            if(area.center.y > c->point.y){
                cout<<"9\n";
                SE->insert(c);
            }

        }

        if(area.center.x > c->point.x){
            cout<<"10\n";

            if(area.center.y < c->point.y){
                cout<<"11\n";
                NW->insert(c);
            }
            if(area.center.y > c->point.y){
                cout<<"12\n";
                SW->insert(c);
            }

        }

        cout<<"13\n";
        return 0;

    }
/*output:
1
2    good
0
1
4
6
10
12
1
2
13    shouldn't reach this spot
0
0
0x61feec
0x61fee0

*/
```

EDIT 2:
sorry forgot to upload my updated (only showing main and insert because nothing else changed) code so here it is:

```
Node *insert(Node *c){
        if(area.w >= 1 && area.h >= 1){
            if(child == NULL){
                child = c;
                return child;
            }
            if(child != NULL){
                if(split == false){
                    NW = new Quad( Square(area.x, area.y, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    NE = new Quad( Square(area.w/2, area.y, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    SW = new Quad( Square(area.x, area.h/2, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    SE = new Quad( Square(area.w/2, area.h/2, area.w/2, area.h/2) );

                    split = true;
                }

                if(area.center.x < c->point.x){

                    if(area.center.y < c->point.y){
                        cout<<"NE->";
                        return NE->insert(c);
                    }
                    if(area.center.y > c->point.y){
                        cout<<"SE->";
                        return SE->insert(c);
                    }

                }

                if(area.center.x > c->point.x){

                    if(area.center.y < c->point.y){
                        cout<<"NW->";
                        return NW->insert(c);
                    }
                    if(area.center.y > c->point.y){
                        cout<<"SW->";
                        return SW->insert(c);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        cout<<"failure\n";
        return NULL;

    }
int main() {

    Node node_1( Point(10, 10) , 3);
    Node node_2( Point(2, 2) , 2);
    Node node_3( Point(6, 6) , 4);
    Node node_4( Point(12, 12) , 6);
    Node node_5( Point(7, 7) , 10);
    Quad quad( Square(0, 0, 16, 16) );
    cout<<quad.insert(&node_1)<<"\nnew node\n";
    cout<<quad.insert(&node_2)<<"\nnew node\n";
    cout<<quad.insert(&node_3)<<"\nnew node\n";
    cout<<quad.insert(&node_4)<<"\nnew node\n";
    cout<<quad.insert(&node_5)<<"\n";
    cout<<quad.test();

    return 0;
}
/*output:    these are good outputs
0x23fdfc
new node
SW->0x23fdf0
new node
SW->SE->0x23fde4
new node
NE->0x23fdd8
new node
SW->SE->NE->0x23fdcc
0x23fdfc
/*
```

if anyone has any tips on how I could make this better it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend turning on warnings (not all paths return a value in Quad::insert) and doing some good old fashioned debugging. Step through and see where it goes bad. Thanks for making a good test case and providing the actual/expected output. On the second call to insert, if you step through, it will fall out very quickly, doing nothing.

Comment: What is the meaning of the return value of `insert(...)`? And why do you expect `test()` to return `NULL`?

Comment: so the reason for insert() returning either true or false is because this is gonna be used for collision detection and I need to see whether or not nodes are colliding if they aren't when they should I have a problem if they are when they should no problem. test() should return null  because the root should've split into 4  and the child of root would then belong to one of the sub quads of the root.

Comment: just wanted to say sorry for taking so long to respond I had some stuff to do. @KennyOstrom thanks I will run it through my GCC, most of this code was made and tested on Sololearn so I could edit it on my phone while I'm away from my computer so I didn't get all of the errors (this 2nd comment was made because the original didn't have enough characters to fit this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
      ...
      if(area.center.y > c->point.y){
        cout<<"12\n";
        SW->insert(c);
      }
    }
    cout<<"13\n";
    return 0;
  }
```

the `SW->insert(c)` invokes a second call to `insert(...)`, and when that call reaches `return`, control returns to *this* call, not to `main()` which is above it in the call stack. So then control passes out of the `if` statement and proceeds to `cout<<"13\n"`. I suggest you put a `return` statement after `SW->insert(c);`.

A more serious problem is here:

```
split = true;
child = NULL;
```

When you split a quad into new quads, you *discard* the node that was already there. I doubt that what what you intended.

As for the last lines of the output:

```
0
0x61feec
0x61fee0
```

I don't know what they mean; they don't appear when I run your code. You must have made some other change to `main` without telling us.

Comment: I feel really disappointed in my self for not knowing to put those return statements. I did away with the child = NULL as soon as i realized what it was doing not too long ago, as for the output i forgot what i did but i believe i was outputting the adress of node_2. Thank you so much for the help these quadtrees have been giving me a headache for the past 6 months (i only started the coding 2 months ago the other 4 i was trying to understand whats happening and why)